# Matching a tag with default not doing what I expect

Tags: c++

I was writing a function with an iterator tag to deal with different iterators.  However, I wanted to make a fallback, so used a template.  I would have expected that the template would have a lower precedence match then conversion to a base type.  I was wrong:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(std::forward_iterator_tag) {
  cout << "forward_iterator_tag" << endl;
}
void test(std::random_access_iterator_tag) {
  cout << "random_access_iterator_tag" << endl;
}
template <typename TAG>
void test(TAG x) {
  cout << "other tag" << endl;
}

int main(){
  test(bidirectional_iterator_tag{});
  return 0;
}
```

I would have expected that this program would print out `forward_iterator_tag`, but instead it matched on `other tag`.

I was trying to make sense of this by reading [Best viable function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function), but I didn't actually see (or maybe I just didn't understand) that which would say which would be taken first.  Thinking about this more I realize I can use the `...` parameter instead of a template as the ellipsis parameter has the lowest priority, but I would like to understand what is going on here and why.

Comment: Bullet point 1 says it. "there is at least one argument of F1 whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of F2".

Comment: ^ this, the template is a better match because no conversion is required (as far as i understand the rules)

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I understand now.

Comment: @Adrian if you understand it now, then post an answer. I'd like to see how you'd "fix" it. For example using an enable_if-not-convertible-from template meta-argument?

Comment: @PatrickParker No, I wouldn't use `enable_if` for this.  More work for the compiler.  Just use an ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

So a template parameter is a better match because it can convert into the exact type.  When compared with a derived type, the exact match wins out.

To "fix", use the ellipsis as the parameter and it will be selected when all other options fail.

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(std::forward_iterator_tag) {
  cout << "forward_iterator_tag" << endl;
}
void test(std::random_access_iterator_tag) {
  cout << "random_access_iterator_tag" << endl;
}
void test(...) {
  cout << "other tag" << endl;
}

int main(){
  test(bidirectional_iterator_tag{});
  return 0;
}
```

Which will now output `forward_iterator_tag` as I wanted.  This is described in [Ranking of implicit conversion sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences), where it states:

> 1. A standard conversion sequence ***is always better than a*** user-defined conversion sequence or an ***ellipsis conversion sequence***.
> 2. A user-defined conversion sequence ***is always better than an ellipsis conversion sequence.***

Emphasis mine.